# Set property of FirstViewModel.cs in MvvmCross

Tags: mvvmcross

I am creating a PCL using `MvvmCross` in Visual Studio 2013. In my `FirstViewModel.cs` file there is one property of type string named `Name`. I want to **set its value through my Android app's `View.cs` file upon clicking a specific button**. How can I achieve this?

Comment: @Stuart Sir , Please guide me about this.

Comment: I'd suggest you take a look through the first 10 videos and code in http://mvvmcross.blogspot.com